# Android background service, automatically fill data

Tags: android, service

I have and android app that has some text fields. When I open this app I have to login with my username and password, and then I have to fill these `textboxes` with information.
Now what I need is to create an app that when opened starts an android background process. So far so good, I can do all that. Now my question is this.
Is is possible for this background service to open the process of the APP and Fill all the `textboxes` with the info I want automatically?

Comment: what do you want to do? just fill a form? I think it's better to do it from inside the Activity. If you still want to communicate from that background service, you need to make it a bound service so that you can communicate with the Activity, then you implement an Interface in the Activity that you will retain in the Service, from there you can communicate with the Activity and modify whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

As per I understand your question, you are trying to update the textbox using the background thread and not android service. If that is the case, then in Android, only the UI thread can update the user interface (UI) and by default all our code runs on UI thread.  But in your case, if fetching the contents of the textbox is taking long time and you do not want the UI to be hung up, then you can fetch the contents using a background thread and pass on the contents to the UI thread which can then update the textbox. AsyncTask class can be used to achieve this.

But if you really want to use android service, then you can use bound services. All services in android run in the same process space as the application and by default, all services run on UI thread.